URL on local server vs. live server
I make an fsockopen() for an HTTP-request to an Smart-Plugin in my home WLAN. On my local server (connected to my home WLAN too) it works fine. But if the (php) script is running on an extern host, the fsockopen don't work any more. I guess the $host is different. How can i make an HTTP-Request from 'outside' to a device in my WLAN?
This is the PHP-Script how it works local:
$host= '192.168.1.33';                      / the adress in my local WLAN
$port= 80;

@$fp= fsockopen($host,$port,$errno,$errstr,6);          // open connection

// if not local, $fp always is FALSE, 

Thanks for thinking!
I tried to find the right URL, but i don't know enough about Net-connection an IP-adresses and Networks and so on. (neither does ChatGPT ;-)

If by "extern host" you mean something that's in some datacenter ("in the cloud"), then you either need to expose the smart-plugin to the internet via port forwarding/proxying (really bad idea, IMO) or set up some kind of VPN to allow access to the device from outside. This is fundamentally just a question about network topology. 192.168.1.33 is a non-routable ip address. It only has some potential meaning within the context of a local area network, it's never routed over the internet.

Yes, by 'external' I mean a live server at an internet provider. I have since learned that it is a problem with the network, not the plugin. That helps already.
Maybe it would work if I could find out the public IP of the device.

If it's a device on your local network, then it most likely doesn't have a public IP due to NAT: in 99% of all home setups at most the router on the outside has a public IP and anything inside will only ever get private link-local IPs.

You will need to do a few things:

talk to your ISP to make sure they won't block incoming connection to your WAN.  They may charge you extra for that feature.

send the HTTP request to your WAN's public IP/port. If you don't know what your current WAN IP is (or if it changes periodically), then you should subscribe to a DynDNS service that creates a static hostname which you can send requests to, and then you can use a DynDNS client (your router might even have one built-in) to keep the hostname updated with your current WAN IP.

setup Port Forwarding on your WAN, so that incoming connections get routed to your HTTP server on your LAN.


